# How to use jQuery in setAfterElementHtml

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, adminform

I add script tag in my admin form like this:

```
$field->setAfterElementHtml('<script>
    //<![CDATA[

    jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
       alert( "ready!" );

    });

   //]]>
</script>');
```

but i got an error like this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined